# haskell beginner - recursive recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

Just starting with Haskell, and I put together this ugly piece to determine the numbers in a list divisible by a number and all numbers less than it.

```
divis :: (Integral a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
divis _ [] = []
divis n (x:xs)
    | x `mod` n == 0 && n == 2 = x : divis n xs
    | x `mod` n == 0 = divis (n-1) [x] ++ divis n xs
    | otherwise = divis n xs
```

and I can call it like...

```
head (divis 10 [1..])
```

to get the first number in the list, in this case 2520. However, it seems that this is not good enough to efficently solve using a higher number like 20.

How can I fix this raskell of a haskell?

Comment: +1 for "raskell of a haskell"

Comment: My first impression is that the algorithm may not be possible to make efficient - each of the *k* numbers in the list up to the first result has to be tested against all of the *n-1* integers between 2 and *n*, so this is looking like a quadratic solution at least.  And when you consider that the relationship of *k* to *n* is superlinear, this is looking like `O(n^3)` or so...

Comment: Thanks much for taking a look, the question started out with me not recursing through [x] or knowing how to accomplish it, but after I had typed out my question, I was able to sort of put it together, but then running it to solve the problem was taking forever, so I thought I would ask anyway, in case I had implemented a poor algorithm.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be improved substantially by using a different algorithm: The smallest number which can be divided by a set of numbers (in this case, the set is [1..10]) is the least common multiple of those numbers.

Haskell even has a least common multiple function (`lcm`) built-in which you can use:

```
Prelude> foldl lcm 1 [1..10]
2520
```

If you prefer not to use the build-in lcm function (as that's almost cheating :) ), you can do it by using [Euclid's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to calculate the GCD, and then using:

```
lcm a b = a * b `div` gcd a b
```

If you need to find all the numbers in a given list which are divisible by [1..n], you can use the fact that any such number will also be divisible by the least common multiple of [1..n]:

```
divis n xs = filter (\x -> x `mod` mult == 0) xs
    where mult = foldl lcm 1 [1..n]
```

Comment: instantaneous vs several long minutes, thank you, still have so much to learn

Comment: Prefer `foldr` (when you can lazily stream structures) or `foldl'` (when the best strategy is strict evaluation) over `foldl`.